# How do you increase the size of an image?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to display an image in NSImageView. However when I place an object into my window (through interface builder), the image in the cell appears very small. How do I increase the size?

I am NOT talking about increasing the size of the cell - I am talking about increasing the size of the image IN the cell. I know increasing the size of the cell would increase the size of my image, but right now a lot of space in the cell is blank. I want to make my image take up more space in the cell.

Note I am on OSX Snow Leopard and I am developing a desktop app, not an iOS one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy API documentation, Batman! See [`-[NSImageView setImageScaling:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImageView/setImageScaling:), or the Scaling control in Interface Builder.

[image: Scaling Control in IB]